# Nullable DecimalField returns 'This value must be a decimal number' when blank

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a field in my model that's of type `DecimalField`. Even though I have `blank=True` and `null=True` in the options, when my model goes through form validation and that field is blank, I get an error 'This value must be a decimal number.' Can `DecimalField`s not be null? I could set a default of 0 for this field but I'd rather leave it nullable.

NOTE: This field originally was *not* nullable, but I changed the model via a South migration to make the field nullable. I double checked the database to confirm that the column has Not NULL? = No.

Here's the field definition from the model:

```
reqwest_max = models.DecimalField("Maximum $", max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

The ModelForm definition is:

```
class ReqwestDetailsForm(ModelForm):
  details = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'span8'}),
                            label = 'What do you need help with?',
                            required=False)
  reqwest_max = forms.CharField(label = "Will Pay Up To $",
                                required=False)

  class Meta:
    model = Reqwest
    widgets = {
      'tags': TextInput(attrs={'size':75}),
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the form definition?

Comment: Do you want to see the ModelForm class or the front end/html?

Comment: and that's why I hate South..

Comment: Edited the post with the ModelForm

Comment: @julio.alegria I don't think it has anything to do with South, since the column definitions in the database are correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `forms.CharField` will return an empty string, not `None` (Python's `NULL`). Therefore it tries to set the column to `''` (empty string), not `NULL`.

You should probably use a `django.forms.DecimalField` in the form. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#decimalfield